How to use Measure to calculate yes and no in column
Need to calculate yes and no in columns by using measure or any other method
Here is the actual table view:

Where we need Power Bi output like this:


First you need to unpivot your table. Select the Patient column, and unpivot others.

The result should look like this:

Then create 2 measures:
Yes Count = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table Unpivot', 'Table Unpivot'[Value] = "Yes"))

No Count = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table Unpivot', 'Table Unpivot'[Value] = "No"))

Add them into your visual:


Hi @ttruhcheva When I tried to "Unpivot Only Selected Columns" then it is not creating seperate table as I can see in your screenshot. it is unpivot rows in the same dateaset which means rows increased by (No of rows * unpivot columns)

Sorry for the late answer. In order to create separate unpivoted table, duplicate the table you want to unpivot, and work on it. Rename it accordingly.
